# Why am I getting this error when using CiviRules

Tags: error, civirules

I'm on D7, Civi 4.6.10, most recent version of civiRules, twilio sms extension.

I get the below errors when I add a rule as follows:
1. create new rule.
2. name: SMS Birthday, trigger: Individual has Birthday
3. add action: Send SMS, Delay action: by number of minutes 540 (my thinking is this will delay the text message till at least 8am)
4. Click Save and get the errors below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ignore_condition_with_delay in CRM_Civirules_Form_RuleAction->postProcess() (line 88 of /home/web_location/civicrm_extensions/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Form/RuleAction.php).
Strict warning: Declaration of CRM_Smsapi_CivirulesAction::alterApiParameters() should be compatible with CRM_CivirulesActions_Generic_Api::alterApiParameters($parameters, CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_TriggerData $triggerData) in require_once() (line 9 of /home/web_location/civicrm_extensions/org.civicoop.smsapi/CRM/Smsapi/CivirulesAction.php).
```

Answer (score 2):

This very likely has the same root cause as civirules issue [#45](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/commit/66e022dd71691f4a7c91c774c17749f58e4264c4).  You may want to install CiviRules from master, or apply the change linked to above, or wait for version 1.2.

Comment: Tried re-installing with master and still getting the following error:   Strict warning: Declaration of CRM_Smsapi_CivirulesAction::alterApiParameters() should be compatible with CRM_CivirulesActions_Generic_Api::alterApiParameters($parameters, CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_TriggerData $triggerData) in require_once() (line 9 of /home/mydomain/org.civicoop.smsapi/CRM/Smsapi/CivirulesAction.php).